# How to parse USER-AGENT field in http header using regex?

Tags: regex

I want to parse some information from the `User-Agent:` HTTP header. The problem is that I'm getting two `User-Agent:` HTTP headers in the same HTTP Request:

```
CONNECT www.facebook.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.facebook.com
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (http://iim.com/a.jph) AppleWebKit/536.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1092.
CONNECT www.facebook.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.facebook.com
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1092.
CONNECT www.facebook.com:443 HTTP/1.1
```

I want the regex to match the non-http portion e.g **Windows NT 6.1; WOW64**. The flow analyzer software I'm using java regex engine.

**My attempts**

```
User-Agent:\s+.*?\((.*?)\)
```

Its matching both; I want to skip http portion of it.

Answer (score 2):

Use a negative lookahead to prevent the match of http:

```
User-Agent:\s+.*?\((?!http)(.*?)\)
```

Though you might want to change the `.*?` to negated classes:

```
User-Agent:[^(]+\((?!http)([^)]+)\)
```

Comment: The `\s+` becomes unnecessary if you do `[^(]+`, which is indeed what I would also advice rather than `.*?`

Comment: I'm wondering if a user agent ever has the OS like `Linux (Ubuntu) 12.10`, where you wanna catch what's after the first `)`...

Comment: @funkwurm If you're curious, you can try: `User-Agent:[^(]+\((?!http)((?:[^)]|\((?1)\))+)\)`